# trouble with spaces in environment variable in rsync script on MacOS

Tags: macos, rsync, environment-variables, bash-scripting, escaping

I have a Bash script that I plan to run for daily backups (my HOME is /Volumes/Norman Data/me):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Halt the script on any errors.
set -e

# Remote server where
remote_server="example.com"

# Destination Folder on Remote Server
target_path="backup/"

# User (with sshy key) on remote server
usr="me"


# ${HOME} evaluates to '/Volumes/Norman Data/me'
# A list of absolute paths to backup. 
include_paths=(
  # "~/.ssh"
  # "~/.bash_history"
  "${HOME}/.bash_profile"
  # "~/.vimrc"
  # "~/.gitconfig"
  # "~/.gitignore"
  # "~/.zshrc"
  # "~/Artifacts"
  "${HOME}/Documents" 
  "--exclude=remote"
  # "~/Downloads"
  # "~/Desktop"
  # "~/Pictures"
  # "~/Projects --exclude 'remote'"
  # "~/Movies"
)

# A list of folder names and files to exclude.
exclude_paths=(
  ".bundle"
  "node_modules"
  "tmp"
)

# Passing list of paths to exclude
for item in "${exclude_paths[@]}"
do
  exclude_flags="${exclude_flags} --exclude=${item}"
done

# Passing list of paths to copy
for item in "${include_paths[@]}"
do
  include_args="${include_args} '${item}'"
done


str="rsync -auvzP ${exclude_flags} ${include_args} ${usr}@${remote_server}:${target_path}"
echo "Running: ${str}"
${str}
```

Running that results in:

```
building file list ... 
rsync: link_stat "/Volumes/Norman" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: link_stat "/Volumes/Norman Data/me/Data/me/.bash_profile" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: link_stat "/Volumes/Norman" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: link_stat "/Volumes/Norman Data/me/Data/me/Documents" failed: No such file or directory (2)
0 files to consider

sent 29 bytes  received 20 bytes  32.67 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at 
/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-52/rsync/main.c(996) [sender=2.6.9]
```

As far as I can tell, the space in the value of my `HOME` is causing problems. I thought quoting it like `"${HOME}/.bash_profile"` would take care of the spaces. And it seems to, kind of. By this I mean, the value I get from `echo "Running: ${str}"` is

```
rsync -auvzP  --exclude=.bundle --exclude=node_modules --exclude=tmp  '/Volumes/Norman Data/me/.bash_profile' '/Volumes/Norman Data/me/Documents' --exclude=remote me@example.com:backup/
```

And when I run that directly in the terminal or paste it in the script (in place of `${str}`, it works as expected. The errors above only happen when using the variable.

Can't seem to figure out what I'm missing here. Can anyone shed some light?

** script adapted from https://gitlab.com/ramawat/randomhacks/blob/master/backup_script.txt

Comment: [bash - Why does shell ignore quotes in arguments passed to it through variables? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136948/why-does-shell-ignore-quotes-in-arguments-passed-to-it-through-variables)

Comment: yikes - that all goes a bit over my head - I just changed `${str}` to `eval ${str}` and things seem to be working fine. But I gather there are some security issues with the use of `eval` on anything not hard coded?

Comment: I'm no bash expert so I can't comment on the security issues. I ran your script through https://www.shellcheck.net/ and looked at the advice. It pointed to that SO question ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right to use arrays to hold parameters, but you should not then try to  flatten the arrays into a single string, as this will then need to be split into words when run as a command, and quoting problems occur.

Simply use arrays all the way through the script, eg accumulate the command in array `cmd`:

```
cmd=(rsync -auvzP)
for item in "${exclude_paths[@]}"
do  cmd+=("--exclude=${item}")
done
for item in "${include_paths[@]}"
do  cmd+=("${item}")
done

cmd+=("${usr}@${remote_server}:${target_path}")

set -x
"${cmd[@]}"
```

If you use `set -x` at the end you will see how the shell is preserving words into a single argument. It shows you the notional quoting it is using:

```
+ rsync ... '/Volumes/Norman Data/me/.bash_profile' ...
```

Comment: aaaaah i think i get how the arrays are supposed to be use. For some reason, with your code, it's adding an extra `/` before the quoted path... `rsync: link_stat "/'/Volumes/Norman Data/me/.ssh'" failed: No such file or directory (2)`. I can't figure out where it's coming from. The part from the `set -x` looks like this: `+ rsync ... ''\''/Volumes/Norman Data/me/.ssh'\''' ...`

Comment: actually, taking the single ticks out of my file paths in the `include_paths` array fixed that problem. **BUT** how can I add a `--exclude` for a specific path without them? As you can see in my array, `${HOME}/Documents` needs to exclude `remote`, but I can't add `remote` to the `exclude_paths` array because other paths may contain a `remote` directory that **SHOULDN'T** be excluded. So close. Any ideas?

Comment: Just make the single string `"directory --exclude=remote"` into 2 strings in the include array, `"directory" "--exclude=remote"`, as you want them to be 2 separate arguments to the final command.

Comment: Perfect - that does the trick!